# Simple XML with Android 4.1

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, simple-framework

I don't know why but as soon as I add simple-xml-2.6.4.jar too my android project I get a Davlik error. This use to work fine before I upgraded to the Android SDK 4.1. (previous 4.0.3)

I started a new android project and just added the lib and it broke instantly so it's not something else in my project. Anyone have any ideas how to de serialize XML now??

Comment: It would be nice if you add logcat of the error.

Comment: Nothing in logcat. It does build. :P All I have is "[2012-07-12 16:55:28 - Blabla] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2012-07-12 16:55:28 - Blabla] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1"

Comment: I've also seen that once the Dalvik starts It doesn't stop if I remove Simple.jar

Comment: Try running dx with the --verbose flag.

Comment: How do I switch on verbose mode in eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

I had a project using simple-xml at first, then we discovered the app runs quite slow when transforming xml into object.

We spent some time to investigate and find out that the system keeps doing GC. When the request or response contains more data, the GC happens every second.

Anyway, we changed to SAX later on and re-write all the xml communication layer which causing a lot of extra work. That's my experience and hopefully will be useful to you, although it may not answer what you exactly ask.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, perhaps this should be shortened into a comment?